# Check minimum checked Checkboxes

Tags: 8, webforms

i am new to the drupal world.

I have created a web form, there are several checkboxes there. like:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

I would like to check whether at least X of the checkboxes are selected before sending. I have no idea how to set it up.

I would be very happy to hear from you.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need one item to be checked, setting the field as required would be the only thing you need to do. When you are in build mode of the webform and you click the element that needs this setting, there is a section called "FORM VALIDATION." If you click to expand this, there is a checkbox to make it required.

Update: the Webform documentation shows [how to add custom validation to a Webform](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element).

Comment: Many thanks for your response. This would be possible with only one checkbox, but unfortunately not if there should be 2 or more.

Comment: Ah, I see. I read this question wrong. So, I think you’ll have to do custom JavaScript validation to verify that there is at least one value from one of the checkboxes. Webform has great documentation including the [cookbook for handlers](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element) for just such a purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. don't have that much programming knowledge yet